# Changing noise level with 24-Bit A/D Converter

Tags: adc, noise

I work on a 8 Channel 24-Bit A/D-Converter. I have an issue with the noise level of this converter. There are some "quiet" periods where the noise is low and acceptable and there are other times where the noise increases by a factor of 5.  [image: Noise changing with time]

Y-Axis is in mV, X-Axis in minutes, sample rate is 2Hz, the pcb board electronic is in a aluminum case to reduce the general noise. The A/D conversion part of the electronics looks like this:

[image: A/D part]

The AD converter is the [AD7190 from analog devices](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad7190.html). Prior to the A/D conversion part we use the following electronic to scale the incoming signals to the A/D converter range:
[image]

I tested the electronics connected to a function generator, with open inputs, in a case and without a case several times at different locations and i always get a behaviour like that...
**My Question is what is the reason for this behavior and how can i "fix" it?**  many thanks in advance!

Comment: Two issues: why are you capacitively coupling the input channels together? That doesn’t make sense to me. Also, Your differential amplifiers have a gain of 1/2, that is a Nader unity, that could cause the instability.

Comment: The capacitive coupling is recommended in the AD7190 data sheet. I am sorry but what is a Nader unity?

Comment: autocorrect strikes again, that should have read “over unity”.

Comment: Do you, for instance, have central heating? It's entirely possible that your circuit is picking up blower motor noise when the boiler is being heated. Or maybe a neighbor has some sort of power tool that is emitting EMI. Just having a circuit in a metal box does not guarantee that your shielding is working as you wish. At the very least, you have wires running to the outside world, and you need to ensure that they are not picking up garbage. Also note that the noise may be entering your box via power conductors, and getting picked up by inputs. Noise is sneaky.

Comment: Given the use of 51.5Kohm and 10nF in the circuits, or 160Hertz bandwidth, what are you measuring? Also, the input opamps attenuate the signal by 2:1, using 100Kohm resistors. (2 of them, thus the total noise contribution is 200Kohm, or 14 nanoVolt per rthz noise Density. At about 200Hz bandwidth, the input-referred noise is 14nV *sqrt(200) = 14 * 14 = 200 nanoVolts RMS noise. How does this compare with your 24-bit quanta?

Comment: PSRR of the OPAMPS is 70 dB at 100Hz. Will your power supplies support 0.5 uV Quanta (5v/2^24 is approx. 0..5 uV)? Are your power supplies the source of the noise, injected thru the opamps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be many sources of noise, I'll cover a few:

1) Temperature. Temperature changes in the electronics can create noise in electronics, especially those of low level measurements. With ADC's you can find the temperature coefficents in the datasheet listed as ppm or in a graph like this:

[image]
Source: AD7190 datasheet

Usually it's a good idea to temperature control low level analog electronics

The other problem is [air on chips](https://books.google.com/books?id=N42wM6vtAhkC&pg=PA846&lpg=PA846&dq=op%20amp%20cover%20foam%20cup%20noise%20air&source=bl&ots=Ruojx8a87S&sig=wTfoOxHwn0A4nDuXXXgz5nI3vr4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3x_2xh7beAhUxLn0KHRBjAioQ6AEwA3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=op%20amp%20cover%20foam%20cup%20noise%20air&f=false), take a cover and put it over the board if you haven't done so already.

2) Power and conducted emissions
One of the biggest problems is common mode noise (noise getting in through the ground), if you have other loads that are switching these can cause problems (especially if the return currents for those loads cross the analog subsection of the PCB) 
DC to DC converters can wreck havoc on low level measurements, make sure your supplies are noise free, and you use good regulators for the power.

3) Radiated noise. Remember that 5/2^24 is 63nV, it's not that hard to get 63nV of noise from radio sources on your PCB (and that means even less before the amplifier, because the amplifier gains up noise). Make sure your inputs to the amplifiers and electronics are properly shielded.

[image]
Source: [Art of Electronics 3rd ed](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2960712)

Answer (score 3):

One amp at 60Hz has dI/dT of 377 amps/second.

If that, modeled as a SINGLE INFINITE WIRE, is 1 meter from your differential inputs, those +/- wires running 1meter with 1cm separation, we compute the magnetically-induced differential noise as

Vinduce = [ 2e-7 * Area/Distance ] * dI/dT

Inserting numbers, we have

Vinduce = 2e-7 * (1meter * 1cm)/1meter * 377 amp/secod

Vinduce = 2e-7 * 1cm * 377 = 0.754 microVolts

without **ANY** powerline spikes from motors or microwave ovens, etc. Microwave ovens easily increase this dI/dT (the 377) by 1,000X or 10,000X, and you would have 7 millivolts of trash.
Using twisted pair might drop the interference by 10X, to 700 microVolts of trash.